# A puzzling step in a solution for "Find $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$, if $a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)=c$"

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

A textbook problem:

> Find $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$, if $a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)=c$

The solution from the textbook:

> Let's divide each term of this equation by $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$:
>   $$\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\sin(x)+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\cos(x)=\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$
>   Since the sum of squares of $\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ and $\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ equals 1, then there will always exist an angle, let's call it $\phi$, for which 
>   $$\sin(\phi)=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}};$$
>   $$\cos(\phi)=\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$
>   Using this, let's transform our equation to
>   $$\sin(\phi)sin(x)+cos(\phi)cos(x)=\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$
>   This will bring us to
>   $$\cos(x-\phi)=\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

This I understand. But the next step is:

> It is evident from this that 
>   $$\sin(x-\phi)=\pm\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2-c^2}}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

Could you give me a hint regarding this last transformation?

Comment: $\sin^2 (x-\phi) + \cos^2 (x-\phi) =1$

Comment: @AnuragA - that was fast, thank you!

Comment: CopperKettle?  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper_Kettle.  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis Cheers to you too! You might try looking who started that Wikipedia article. (0:

Comment: Ha!  I should have known!  ***Well Done!!!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sin^2(x-\phi)+\cos^2(x-\phi)=1$$
$$\sin(x-\phi)=\pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x-\phi)}$$ 
But $\cos(x-\phi)=\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$

Therefore $\sin(x-\phi)=\pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x-\phi)}=\pm\sqrt{1-(\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}})^2}=\pm\sqrt{1-\frac{c^2}{a^2+b^2}}$

This gives: $\pm\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}{a^2+b^2}-\frac{c^2}{a^2+b^2}}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{a^2+b^2}}$

I believe this is explanatory enough

Comment: Thank you, this is way simpler! I'll need to read up on why we need that $\pm$ though..

Comment: The $\pm$ sign appears in all even roots (it's a shame I forgot to include it in mine). For instance the square root of 4 is $\pm2$ because $(-2)^2$ is the same as $2^2$ which is 4. Similarly, the fourth root of 81 is $\pm3$. I'm sure you now know why ;)

Comment: Yes, thank you for a reminder, @Obinoscopy!

Answer (score 0):

Using Anurag A's [hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1384945/a-puzzling-step-in-a-solution-for-find-sinx-and-cosx-if-a-sinxb#comment2820024_1384945),

$$\sin(x-\phi)=\pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x-\phi)}$$ 
Since 
$$\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)^2=1,$$
$$\sin(x-\phi)=\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)^2-\left(\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)^2};$$ 
$$\sin(x-\phi)=\pm\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2-c^2}}{\sqrt{\left(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\right)^2}}=\pm\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2-c^2}}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you posted like this:

~~~~~

for which

$$\cos(\phi)=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}};$$
$$\sin(\phi)=\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$
Using this, let's transform our equation to

$$\cos(\phi)\sin(x)+\sin(\phi)\cos(x)=\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

This will bring us to

$$ \sin(x+\phi)=\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

This I understand. But the next step is:

> It is evident from this that

$$\cos(x+\phi)=\pm\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2-c^2}}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

Could you give me a hint regarding this last transformation?

~~~~

You can see not immediately catching the $\sin, \cos $ Pythagorean relationship.